# How to go to rootViewController bottomnavigationbar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I implemented `bottomnavigationbar` in the app with two tabs `Page A & Page B`. In Page B contains one button at the center.
What i want to achieve is that if i click on the button in `Page B` then it should be back to rootViewController just like in native iOS, so how to achieve this in flutter. Below is the dart code

> main.dart

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: App(),
    );
  }
}
class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => AppState();
}
class AppState extends State<App> {
  static int currentTab = 0;
  final List<TabItem> tabs = [
    TabItem(
      tabName: "Page A",
      icon: Icons.home_outlined,
      page: PageA(),
    ),
    TabItem(
      tabName: "Page B",
      icon: Icons.search,
      page: PageB(),
    ),
  ];
  AppState() {
    tabs.asMap().forEach((index, details) {
      details.setIndex(index);
    });
  }
  void _selectTab(int index) {
    if (index == currentTab) {
      tabs[index].key.currentState!.popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
    } else {
      setState(() => currentTab = index);
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        final isFirstRouteInCurrentTab =
            !await tabs[currentTab].key.currentState!.maybePop();
        if (isFirstRouteInCurrentTab) {
          if (currentTab != 0) {
            _selectTab(0);
            return false;
          }
        }
        return isFirstRouteInCurrentTab;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: IndexedStack(
          index: currentTab,
          children: tabs.map((e) => e.page).toList(),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigation(
          onSelectTab: _selectTab,
          tabs: tabs,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> TabItem.dart

```
class TabItem {
  final String tabName;
  final IconData icon;
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> key = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  int _index = 0;
  late Widget _page;
  TabItem({
    required this.tabName,
    required this.icon,
    required Widget page,
  }) {
    _page = page;
  }
  void setIndex(int i) {
    _index = i;
  }
  int getIndex() => _index;
  Widget get page {
    return Visibility(
      visible: _index == AppState.currentTab,
      maintainState: true,
      child: Navigator(
        key: key,
        onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) {
          return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => _page,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> BottomNavigation.dart

```
class BottomNavigation extends StatelessWidget {
  BottomNavigation({
    required this.onSelectTab,
    required this.tabs,
  });
  final ValueChanged<int> onSelectTab;
  final List<TabItem> tabs;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      items: tabs
          .map(
            (e) => _buildItem(
              index: e.getIndex(),
              icon: e.icon,
              tabName: e.tabName,
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
      onTap: (index) => onSelectTab(
        index,
      ),
    );
  }
  BottomNavigationBarItem _buildItem(
      {required int index, required IconData icon, required String tabName}) {
    return BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(
        icon,
        color: _tabColor(index: index),
      ),
      title: Text(
        tabName,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: _tabColor(index: index),
          fontSize: 12,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  Color _tabColor({required int index}) {
    return AppState.currentTab == index
        ? Colors.red
        : Colors.black;
  }
}
```

Comment: `Navigator.popUntil('/')` When you click, just pop until the root of your application - whatever view you start on when the app launches. It will clear the navigation stack all the way down to where you started. Are you familiar with these navigation options? There are more depending on what you want to happen as/when you navigate back.

Comment: @daddygames It is showing error "The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'." on "/"

Comment: My fault, I did not provide the exact, correct syntax. `Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName("/"));` Be aware that this only works if you have configured the named route "/" inside of you project and if that points to your starting view. You may want to read up on [how navigation works in flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/navigation).